# Annotation subscript doesn't show correctly

Tags: r, formatting, annotations

I am adding an annotation in the 2nd panel of a ggplot2 figure. I wanted something like this:

(b) PM<sub>2.5</sub>

This is the code i used:

```
b <-paste("(b)", expression('PM'[2.5]))

ggplot+annotate("text", x=-3.5, y=0.12, label=b)
```

However, what i got is something like this:

(b) "PM"[2.5]

Anyone can help? Is this because I used gridExtra to put together two figures?

Comment: Don't use `paste` or quoted tokens in expressions: `b <-expression("("*b*")"~PM[2.5]))`  ... you do need to quote parens. Would have tested if you included a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi BondedDust, I tried your code to define b. Now it doesn't show in my figure panel b anymore. But no error message was given too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hadleys's desire to shield users from the inner workings of R formulas he has made it rather difficult to use real R expressions.

```
b <-expression("("*b*")"~PM[2.5])
gf+annotate("text", x=1.5, y=0.12, label=deparse(b), parse=TRUE)
```

My 'x' is different b/c I was using my own test case. This also works:

```
b <- "'('*b*')'~PM[2.5]"
gf+annotate("text", x=1.5, y=0.12, label=b, parse=TRUE)
```

So maybe it's not too difficult. The parsing argument seems to cause it to be fed through a `parse(text=label)` step and then behaves like ordinary plotmath. Might even accept `paste` which is often a confusing (and unnecessary) function in plotmath expressions. See this base graphics equivalent:

```
 plot(1)
 text(1.1, 1.1, label=parse(text=b) )
```

Comment: Hi BondedDust, I tried these out and find a combination of these two commands worked for me:b <-("("*b*")"~PM[2.5]) and gf+annotate("text", x=1.5, y=0.12, label=deparse(b), parse=TRUE). Thank you very much!

Comment: I would not have guessed that your assignment to `b` would succeed, since you have used double-quotes as the outer string delimiter and then also used it inside the string expression. (Throws an error on my machine.)